# How to Port Telegram Sticker Animation .tgs into flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, telegram, lottie, sticker

Telegram has a moving sticker animation using the tgs extension, how to make it work for displaying in a flutter project?

I want the telegram animation sticker to be realized on the flutter widget

Answer (score 0):

I think, this question is a promotion for a https://pub.dev/packages/tgs widget package )

Comment: affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: I do not know about affiliation, but this answer is easy to google today. May be only today...